# Insert a descendant img element's src attribute into parent element's href attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following html:

```
<a href="#">
    <img src="img-1" />
</a>
<a href="#">
    <img src="img-2" />
</a>
<a href="#">
    <img src="img-3" />
</a>
```

What I am trying to do is for each one of the links I need to retrieve its child img src and insert that src into the href respectively.

So the end result would look like this:

```
<a href="img-1">
    <img src="img-1" />
</a>
<a href="img-2">
    <img src="img-2" />
</a>
<a href="img-3">
    <img src="img-3" />
</a>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over each of the `a` elements that have `img` descendants, and grab the corresponding `src` attribute:

```
$('a:has(img)').each(function () {
  this.href = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
});
```

Alternatively, you could also do this without jQuery:

```
var anchors = document.querySelectorAll('a');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(anchors, function (a) {
  var img = a.querySelector('img');
  a.href = img !== null ? a.querySelector('img').getAttribute('src') : a.href;
});
```

Comment: Why not `a > img` in the each selector?

Comment: @Fleuv Because I didn't want to assume that the `img` element was a direct child.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript solution: (I like native solutions )

```js
var images = document.getElementsByTagName("img")
for(var i = 0; i < images.length; ++i) {
  if(images[i].parentElement && images[i].parentElement.tagName === "A")
      images[i].parentElement.href = images[i].src
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
    <img src="img-1" />
</a>
<a href="#">
    <img src="img-2" />
</a>
<a href="#">
    <img src="img-3" />
</a>
```

It will get all Image-Elements in your document, and then apply its src to it's parents href attribute

Answer (score 0):

javascript

```
var all_images=document.getElementsByTagName('img')
for(var i=0;i<all_images.length;++i){
all_images[i].parentNode.href=all_images[i].src;
console.log(all_images[i].parentNode.href)
}
```